# Symfony 2 Form_Login Auth , login_check will not Authenticate

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form_login system, when I attempt to login , it hits the login_check method that symfony handles internally.

But I get:

> Full authentication is required to access this resource.

Now I understand this as my firewall is active on that url.
What is confusing me is that login_check from the docs here:

[Avoid Common Pitfalls](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#avoid-common-pitfalls)

tells me that login_check path has to be behind a firewall or else it will
try and search for non-existent controller I will need to create.

I am completely confused.

Here is my security.yml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Brs\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: BrsUserBundle:User, property: fname }

    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            context: website
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            context: website
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                #default_target_path: /admin/hello
                #failure_path: /hello/1
            # logout:
            #     path: /admin/logout
                #target: /admin/hello
                # invalidate_session: false
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: I would try commenting out everything in the access_control section and see what happens then.

Comment: I then get:
Unable to find the controller for path "/admin/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

Comment: The reason why i get that is because it needs to be behind a firewall.

Comment: Yes, but you can use a firewall without access_controll, even if it's not every usefull.

Comment: logs here it helps?: http://pastie.org/9957477

Comment: Can you post the changes you have made to your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you have your check login path in a restricted area.

```
        check_path: /admin/login_check

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

basically you're saying that only authenticated users can authenticate.  you need to change your check path to something that isn't locked behind an access control or tell your access control that admin/login_check is ok for non authenticated users.

e.g.

```
check_path: /login_check
```

or

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
```